# Is there a way to set app to fullscreen mode when developing an app with WinUI 3 (Project Reunion)?

Tags: c#, winui-3

There doesn't appear to be any options for setting my app to fullscreen mode while building WinUI3/Project Reunion-based apps. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are no options. You have to wait until at least 0.8.
Top-level Windows management is still not production ready at the moment. You can find it on the older WinUI3 roadmap.

And I personally wouldn't assume that it's good enough in 0.8 and assume that we have to wait until 1.0 at the end of year.

Comment: Hi do you have any new information about fullscreen in WinUI 3. I can't find any.